# Looping over a range, row by row

Tags: vba, excel

I have some data that looks like this:

[image]

For all rows labeled "Coupon" I want to add a number to the entries in that row if they are non-blank. If they are blank, I want to leave them alone. Also if the data in a cell happen to be a date, I want to not touch it.

Row by row I want to run through the entire range.

My current code is giving me a "for each may only iterate over a collection object or an array vba" error. Please help!

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim rng As Range
Dim rw As Range
Dim cel As Range


Set rng = Range("E15:P464")

For Each rw In rng.Row
    If rw.Item(1, 1) = "coupon" Then
      For Each cel In rw.Cells
            If IsEmpty(cel.Value) = False Then
                   If Not IsDate(cel) Then
                       cel.Value = cel.Value + 0.0001
                   End If
            End If
      Next cel
    End If
Next rw



End Sub
```

Comment: You want `rng.Rows` with an s

Comment: You'll also need `rw.Cells(1,1)` rather than `rw.Item(1,1)`.  Item will give an `Application-defined or object-defined error`.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thx. After changing it to rows I get "Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thx. Now I am getting a "Type mismatch" error.

Comment: When you find a coupon row you're adding 0.0001 to each cell in that row - the first cell says `coupon` and you try and add 0.0001 to that which gives the error.  Change your `If Not IsDate(cel) Then` to `If IsNumeric(cel) Then` (the row you're checking doesn't have a date in it).  You could also update `If IsEmpty(cel.Value) = False Then` to `If Not IsEmpty(cel.Value) Then`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I just realized this myself. Thank you!

Comment: @Amatya  try code in answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chris neilsen gave solution to fix the error

you may want to follow an alternative [`AutoFilter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) approach, like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cel As Range

    With Worksheets("Coupons") '<--| reference "Coupons" worksheet (change "Coupons" to your actual worksheet name)
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<--| reference its range made of cells contiguous to "A1"
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Coupon" '<--| filter it on column "A" with "Coupon" criteria
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any "Coupon" in column A" has been filtered
                For Each cel In .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<-- loop through filtered range cells containing numbers (and skipping column "A" and row 1)
                    If Not IsDate(cel) Then cel.Value = cel.Value + 0.0001 ' update non-date numbers
                Next cel
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| show all rows back
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me a totally different and possibly way more efficient and versatile method of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, it's a little different than the one you posted:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng         As Range
Dim rw          As Range
Dim Col         As Long
Dim CellStr     As String

Set rng = Range("E15:P464")

' loop through rows in Range
For Each rw In rng.Rows
    ' get the value of the first column and convert to String
    CellStr = rw.Columns(1).Value

    ' use StrComp to verify match between strings
    If StrComp(CellStr, "coupun") = 0 Then

        ' loop through all columns in current row (where there was a match with "coupun"
        For Col = rng.Columns(2).Column To rw.Columns.Count

            ' check if current cell is empty
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(rw.Row, Col)) Then
                If Not IsDate(Cells(rw.Row, Col)) Then
                    Cells(rw.Row, Col).Value = Cells(rw.Row, Col).Value + 0.0001
                End If
            End If
        Next Col

    End If
Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: @user3598756 not following... what _coupun_ do you mean ?

Comment: The one that should be "coupon"..:-)

Comment: @user3598756 actually, watch your "Coupuns" ? not "coupun"

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you!